# assign an image to an array and cant show the array in right way

Tags: python, arrays, image

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
a=np.zeros([10,1080,1920,3])
path="C:\\Users\\zhzh7\\Desktop\\pictures\\ai2.jpg"
img=cv2.imread(path,1)
a[0]=img
print(type(img))
print(type(a[0]))
cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.imshow("a",a[0])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's my code. 
As you can see, i assign the image to a[0] and show a[0] with cv2, but it is almost white, it should be a blue image.[See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03QOM.png)

Dose any one know how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the datatype. `np.zeros()` defaults to `float64` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)), while your image `img` from `cv.imread()` has `dtype=uint8`.

Just add the `dtype` like so:

```
# ...
a=np.zeros([10,1080,1920,3], dtype=np.uint8)
path="C:\\Users\\zhzh7\\Desktop\\pictures\\ai2.jpg"
img=cv2.imread(path,1)
a[0]=img
# ...
```